# Could not write to .bash_profile when installing Rust on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, terminal, rust

I am trying to install Rust by running the following:

```
sudo curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

I keep getting this following error:

```
could not write rcfile file: '/Users/pro/.bash_profile'
info: caused by: Permission denied (os error 13
```

Comment: **Why** are you (attempting to) run it as root?

Comment: Because when I tried it without it was giving this error so I thought using sudo would solve it

Comment: Does that mean that you also get the error when you don't use `sudo`? Please [edit] your question to have the complete shell command you are running, starting with the `curl` command until the next shell prompt.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Give a try using this not using sudo:

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- --help
```

If that works then probably you could try:

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- --no-modify-path
```

If the command with the *--no-modify-path* option works, you'll have to manually update **.bash_profile** to include it in your path:

```
source ~/.cargo/env
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work. Will I need to manually edit the path? what path would I need to change it to if yes?

Comment: Thanks figured it out. Had to add `source ~/.cargo/env` to my .bash_profile

Comment: Gold! I'll update the answer to include the additional step to modify path.

Comment: Rather than update the bash file manually (and `.zshenv` for Mac users using ZSH), consider first checking/changing file permissions on `.bash_profile` and then re-running `rustup` (as suggested in @hasan-a-yousef 's updated answer).   e.g., `sudo chown $(whoami) ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer worked for me in the working terminal session only, it did not work after restarting my MacBokk Air.

The solution worked with me is:

```
// Opened .bash_profile file, I used VS code as editor, this the `code` below
Hasans-Air:~ h_ajsf$ sudo code $HOME/.bash_profile
// Add the below to the .bash_profile file
PATH=$PATH:/Users/$USER/.cargo/bin
//Saved the file
//Updated env by:
Hasans-Air:~ h_ajsf$ source $HOME/.bash_profile
//Check for JAVA_HOME
Hasans-Air:~ h_ajsf$ rustup
```

**UPDATE**

As shown [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/666#issuecomment-253310572):

> It sounds like the user running the install script didn't have
> permission/wasn't owner of ~/.bash_profile, which is unusual. Maybe
> yarn should check and be more helpful, but in any case it's probably a
> good idea to run `sudo chown` whoami `~/.bash_profile`

So, I tried the below command:

```
sudo chown h_ajsf ~/.bash_profile
```

And everything completed smoothly.

[image]

Comment: This seems a better option than the accepted answer because 
1) it addresses underlying problem (file permission) and 
2) unblocks `rustup` which also updates env vars for `.zshenv`... important for new Mac OS users where ZSH is the default shell

`sudo chown $(whoami) ~/.bash_profile` is an alternative